# How to make a default tab in Google Chrome DevTools or make Chrome to remember tab position?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

How to make a default tab in Google Chrome DevTools, or make Chrome to remember tab position?

Currently it always shows tabs in a certain order: Elements, Console, Sources, etc.. I can drag the tabs to change that order, but Chrome doesn't remember it.

Lets say I want Network to be the First tab, how can I do that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can move Elements tab to bottom. Just right-click on Elements tab and click "Move to Bottom".
You can then move the Network tab to the first tab and that will make it the default when you open the dev toools

Answer (score 1):

It not remembering was a bug. I am unable to track down the internal report right off.

It is remembering in M50 and as I recall from the bug report is fixed in M49 (landing in a few weeks to stable.) So things should be good-to-go then.

To make a default, just make that tab position first once it is remembering the order.

Comment: Sorry I missed you here. I am trying to make it first, and it is not remembered.

Comment: That's what I explained. It is a bug in the current stable and should be fixed in the next release.

Comment: Seems to be broken again for me in recent versions, it used to work.